# How to go from scrolling to fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you to this website: https://www.subtask.com/ and scroll down you will notice that the "Ready to increase your productivity? Get started today! |Try it free|" heading becomes a fixed bar as you continue to scroll down.

How can this be implemented? I presume it is CSS based, but I may be wrong and it may be JavaScript. I look forward to hearing from those who know - how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Why not look at the code in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin to do that [Sticky JS](http://stickyjs.com/)